# Difference between DataView.Sort and DataTable.OrderBy().AsDataView()?

Tags: c#, linq, dataview

I have a `DataGridView` which is bound to a `DataTable` that contains a column of custom types that I need to sort by.  This custom type (`MyCustomType`) implements `IComparable<MyCustomType>` which is how I wanted the sorting to work.

I tried 2 methods to create a `DataView` which I would use as the grid's data source:

```
MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "MyCustomField";
```

This did not really work properly - it "almost" worked, but sometimes my rows would not be sorted correctly.

Second method:

```
MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();
DataView dv = dt.OrderBy(row => row.MyCustomField).AsDataView();
```

This seems to be doing what I want.  My question is, what's the difference between these two methods?  Is it possible that `DataView.Sort` is **not** using my `IComparable<T>` implementation, and the LINQ-enabled `DataView` **is**?  Why would that be the case?

Furthermore, does anyone know about the relative performance of non-LINQ-enabled and LINQ-enabled `DataView`s?  It seems like if there isn't a huge performance hit, there's no longer any reason to use the non-LINQ-enabled version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `.Sort` on the DataView, it sorts this particular instance of the object. Your second method actually creates a brand new object and assigns to the `dv` variable. This can be a critical difference.

**EDIT**: Not your second method specifically, since you're not assigning, then re-assigning. But if you had an existing DataView, then re-assigned it using the OrderBy method, then you'd have the scenario I suggested.

Sorry, I wasn't as clear as I should have been.

Comment: Of course, that's not necessarily the difference you're looking for, but it is an important distinction.

Comment: I think I may actually be doing that in my code (`dv = dv.Whatever().AsDataView()`).  Seems like the two methods are hitting very different code within the framework.  I found that you can do some interesting things with whatever `AsDataView` returns, but it starts looking like undocumented voodoo pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting comparisons for anyone else wondering how Linq-DataView performs vs non-Linq-DataView, especially since the results surprised me. For this test, at least, old DataView's an order of magnitude faster than Linq-enabled DataView.

```
v1: Linq-DataView, on-the-fly sort string -> OrderBy/ThenBy via Field<dynamic>()
v2: Linq-DataView, on-the-fly via mapped Field<type>()
v3: Linq-DataView, hard-coded OrderBy/ThenBy
v4: non-Linq DataView w/sort string
```

Linq-DataView vs non-Linq-DataView for untyped dtbl (seconds)

```
03.411  v1 = dtbl.AsEnumerable().OrderBy("T30y, Dat desc").AsDataView();
02.561  v2 = dtbl.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(dtbl, "T30y, Dat desc").AsDataView();
01.573  v3 = dtbl.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(y=>y.Field<decimal>("T30y"))
                                .ThenByDescending(y=>y.Field<DateTime>("Dat")).AsDataView();
00.214  v4 = new DataView(dtbl, "", "T30y, Dat desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

02.403  v1: 100,000 iterations of Find()
01.708  v2: 100,000 iterations of Find()
01.173  v3: 100,000 iterations of Find()
00.261  v4: 100,000 iterations of Find()
```

OrderBy for v2 (with in-line comment for v1)

```
static public EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>
    OrderBy( this EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> ys, DataTable dtbl, string sort )
{
    OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> oys = null;
    foreach ( string s in (sort ?? "").Split(new []{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None) )
    {
        int n = s.IndexOf(" desc");
        string x = n!=-1 ? s.Substring(0, n) : s;
        Type typ = dtbl.Columns[x].DataType;
        Func<DataRow,dynamic> vfn = y=>yget[typ](y,x); // v1: vfn = y.Field<dynamic>(x)

        if ( oys==null )
             oys = s.Contains(" desc") ? ys.OrderByDescending(vfn) : ys.OrderBy(vfn);
        else oys = s.Contains(" desc") ? oys.ThenByDescending(vfn) : oys.ThenBy(vfn);
    }
    return oys ?? ys;
}

static Dictionary<Type,Func<DataRow,string,dynamic>>
    yget = new Dictionary<Type,Func<DataRow,string,dynamic>>
{
    {typeof(bool),     (y,x)=>y.Field<bool>(x)},
    {typeof(short),    (y,x)=>y.Field<short>(x)},
    {typeof(int),      (y,x)=>y.Field<int>(x)},
    {typeof(string),   (y,x)=>y.Field<string>(x)},
    {typeof(decimal),  (y,x)=>y.Field<decimal>(x)},
    {typeof(float),    (y,x)=>y.Field<float>(x)},
    {typeof(double),   (y,x)=>y.Field<double>(x)},
    {typeof(DateTime), (y,x)=>y.Field<DateTime>(x)},
    {typeof(TimeSpan), (y,x)=>y.Field<TimeSpan>(x)},
};
```

If anyone ever sees this and can suggest a way of mapping datacolumns -> Field lambdas without relying on a Func<> returning a dynamic type, any suggestion would be most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

DataView.Sort is a method that is built into the DataView class whereas .OrderBy is an Extension.

Comment: I'm well aware of that documented and simple difference.  I don't see how that does anything to explain the behavior I saw.